# java abstract method with generic type

Tags: java, generics, methods, abstract

I have the following different components of my code:

```
 1) an Interface
 2) an ENum Class (implementing the Interface)
 3) an Abstract Class with an Abstract Method (Problem_Method() below)
 4) a Specific Sub-Class of the Abstract Class
```

Although everything looks good in the Abstract Class, when the Specific Sub-Class defines Problem_Method() (as it is/should be required to do), I get warning messages as though the Override of Problem_Method() is incorrect.  Specifically, it says, "must implement or override a supertype method".  I believe I AM correctly overriding the supertype method.  Does anyone have any idea as to what's going on and/or how to fix it.  Here is the relevant code:

```
public interface My_Interface <K extends Enum <K>> {
    abstract public void Method1 ();
    abstract public void Method2 ();
}

public enum My_ENum implements My_Interface <My_ENum> {
    E1, E2, ...

    public void Method1 () {
         ...
    }
    public void Method2 () {
         ...
    }
}

abstract public class My_Abstract_Class {
    public My_Abstract_Class () {
         ...
    }
    abstract protected boolean Okay_Method ( final My_Abstract_Class param );

    /* the FOLLOWING Method is where the problem comes from */
    abstract protected <My_ENum extends Enum <My_ENum> & My_Interface <My_ENum>> My_Abstract_Class Problem_Method ( final My_ENum value );
}

public class My_Sub_Class extends My_Abstract_Class {
    public My_Sub_Class () {
         super();
         ...
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean Okay_Method ( final My_Abstract_Class param ) {
         boolean result = false;
         ...
         return result;
    }

    /* the FOLLOWING Method is where the problem comes from */
    @Override
    protected My_Abstract_Class Problem_Method ( final My_ENum  param ) {
        My_Sub_Class result = new My_Sub_Class();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn and follow Java coding standards.  This isn't C#: https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html

Comment: Use the same signature of your method in subclass as that of your parent class.

Comment: Instead of describing what you're doing and what doesn't work for you - why won't you describe what is it you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hint: My_ENum as a generic type name vs My_ENum the enum (fixed version: https://ideone.com/qJErtH)